# Refactor KnexJS Multiple Promises

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

I am running multiple select queries using Knexjs and promises. I need all the queries to return a value before I send the results, which I have been able to achieve. However I don't think the code is very optimised.

```
knex(table).select('CRMContactId').where('FCIRecognition', '<', -49.00)
            .then(function(results) {

                data.largeclawbacks = results.length;

                knex(table).select('CRMContactId').where('PlanStatus', 'Out of Force').andWhere(function(){this.whereNot('IncomeType', 'Fund Based Commission').andWhereNot('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission')})
                    .then(function(results) {

                        data.outofforce = results.length;

                        knex(table).select('CRMContactId').where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 2').andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
                            .andWhere((builder) => builder.whereIn('Plantype', ['Flexible Benefits','General Insurance','Group Critical Illness','Group Death In Service','Group Dental Insurance','Group Healthcare Cash Plan','Group Income Protection','Group Life','Group Life;Group Income Protection','Group PMI','Group Travel Insurance']))
                            .andWhereNot('Payable', 0)
                            .then(function(results) {

                                data.tier2 = results.length;

                                knex(table).select('CRMContactId').where((builder) => builder.where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 3').orWhere('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 4')).
                                andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
                                    .andWhere((builder) => builder.whereIn('Plantype', ['Accident Sickness & Unemployment Insurance','AVC','Discretionary Managed Service','Endowment','Enhanced Pension Annuity','Executive Pension Plan','FSAVC','General Investment Account','Income Drawdown','Income Protection','Individual Retirement Account', 'Insurance / Investment Bond','Investment Trust','ISA','Long Term Care','Maximum Investment Plan','Money Purchase Contracted','OEIC / Unit Trust','Offshore Bond','Pension Annuity','Pension Term Assurance','Personal Equity Plan','Personal Pension Plan','Regular Savings Plan','Relevant Life Policy','s226 RAC','s32 Buyout Bond','Savings Account','SIPP','SSAS','Stakeholder Individual','Term Protection','Venture Capital Trust','Whole Of Life','Wrap']))
                                    .andWhereNot('Payable', 0)
                                    .then(function(results) {

                                        data.tier3 = results.length;

                                        knex(table).select('CRMContactId').where('FCIRecognition', '>', 500.00).andWhere('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission')
                                            .then(function(results) {

                                                data.largerenewal = results.length;

                                                knex.raw(`SELECT ContactName AS Adviser, FORMAT(SUM(Payable),2) AS 'Renewal Income' FROM fci_test WHERE IncomeType IN ("Renewal Commission","Fund Based Commission","Ongoing Fee") AND \`Payaways Made/Received\` != 'Payaway Made' GROUP BY ContactName`)
                                                    .then(function(results){

                                                        data.renewalincome = results[0];
                                                        res.send(data)
                                                    })

                                            })
                                    })
                            })
                    })
            })
```

I am sure there is a better way of coding this and getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be concerned first about the readability and then about performance.
By first making the code more readable is easier to see which optimization could be applied.

After some refactoring we can get to a code similar to:

```
knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
  .where('FCIRecognition', '<', -49.00)
  .then(function(results) {

    data.largeclawbacks = results.length;

    knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
      .where('PlanStatus', 'Out of Force')
      .andWhere((builder) => {
        builder.whereNot('IncomeType', 'Fund Based Commission')
          .andWhereNot('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission');
      })
      .then(function(results) {

        data.outofforce = results.length;

        knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
          .where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 2')
          .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
          .whereIn('Plantype', tier2PlanTypes)
          .andWhereNot('Payable', 0)
          .then(function(results) {

            data.tier2 = results.length;

            knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
              .whereIn('GroupOneCaption', ['Tier 3', 'Tier 4'])
              .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
              .whereIn('Plantype', tier3PlanTypes)
              .andWhereNot('Payable', 0)
              .then(function(results) {

                data.tier3 = results.length;

                knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
                  .where('FCIRecognition', '>', 500.00)
                  .andWhere('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission')
                  .then(function(results) {

                    data.largerenewal = results.length;

                    knex.raw(`SELECT ContactName AS Adviser, FORMAT(SUM(Payable),2) AS 'Renewal Income' FROM fci_test 
                              WHERE IncomeType IN ("Renewal Commission","Fund Based Commission","Ongoing Fee") 
                                AND \`Payaways Made/Received\` != 'Payaway Made' GROUP BY ContactName`)
                      .then(function(results){
                          data.renewalincome = results[0];
                          res.send(data)
                      });
                  })
              })
          })
      })
  });
```

It does not look like much, but I can see more clear that **all queries are independent of each other** (I will use this to optimize)

After, further refactoring I save every query in a constant and then use `Promise.all` to issue all of them at once and the way for them to finish in order to send the response.

```
const largeclawbacksQuery = knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
  .where('FCIRecognition', '<', -49.00);

const outofforceQuery = knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
  .where('PlanStatus', 'Out of Force')
  .andWhere((builder) => {
    builder.whereNot('IncomeType', 'Fund Based Commission')
      .andWhereNot('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission')
  });

const tier2Query = knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
    .where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 2')
    .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
    .whereIn('Plantype', tier2PlanTypes)
    .andWhereNot('Payable', 0);

const tier3Query = knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
  .whereIn('GroupOneCaption', ['Tier 3', 'Tier 4'])
  .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
  .whereIn('Plantype', tier3PlanTypes)
  .andWhereNot('Payable', 0);

const largerenewalQuery = knex(table).select('CRMContactId')
  .where('FCIRecognition', '>', 500.00)
  .andWhere('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission');

const renewalincomeQuery = knex.raw(
  `SELECT ContactName AS Adviser, FORMAT(SUM(Payable),2) AS 'Renewal Income' FROM fci_test 
    WHERE IncomeType IN ("Renewal Commission","Fund Based Commission","Ongoing Fee") 
      AND \`Payaways Made/Received\` != 'Payaway Made' GROUP BY ContactName`
);

Promise.all([largeclawbacksQuery, outofforceQuery, tier2Query, tier3Query, largerenewalQuery, renewalincomeQuery])
  .then((result) => {
    res.send({
      largeclawbacks: result[0].length,
      outofforce: result[1].length,
      tier2: results[2].length,
      tier3: results[3].length,
      largerenewal: results[4].length,
      renewalincome: results[4][0],
    });
  });
```

**Important points:**

- whereIn can be chained and they will translate to sql as `WHERE afield IN avalues AND bfield IN bvalues`
- Line length can improve readability and in turn make code easier to read
- We can wait for a query builder to finish its query if we treat it as a promise

**Further improvement:**

- Every method (whereIn, where, orWhere, etc) returns a query builder
  partial query can be reused by cloning a query builder instance as explained [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/209). This could help you define a base query for `tier2Query` and `tier3Query`.
- We can wait for promises to resolve using a better API, using something like [promise-all-properties](https://github.com/marcelowa/promise-all-properties#readme)
- Instead of querying all records to get the value of length you could ask for the `COUNT` directly, this will improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help @cesar-manrique ! I am wanting to pass a value to the variable "table" would I do this by making it a function?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Yes, you can put all in a function and return the Promise.all, but first change res.send by a return. Then when you call your new function you can use it like: myFunction.then((result) => console.log(result)) and get your data printed to the console. This way you keep the mapping of the result in your function.

Comment: This "flat" style of declaring promises (the`const`'s) is much better. Conversely, abusing `.then()` just ends up with deep code that will be tough to follow, and makes changes more annoying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Just to blindly organizing your promises and returning them correctly in chain looks like this:

```
knex(table)
  .select('CRMContactId')
  .where('FCIRecognition', '<', -49.0)
  .then(function(results) {
    data.largeclawbacks = results.length;

    return knex(table)
      .select('CRMContactId')
      .where('PlanStatus', 'Out of Force')
      .andWhere(function() {
        this.whereNot('IncomeType', 'Fund Based Commission').andWhereNot('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission');
      });
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    data.outofforce = results.length;

    return knex(table)
      .select('CRMContactId')
      .where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 2')
      .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
      .andWhere(builder =>
        builder.whereIn('Plantype', [
          'Flexible Benefits',
          'General Insurance',
          'Group Critical Illness',
          'Group Death In Service',
          'Group Dental Insurance',
          'Group Healthcare Cash Plan',
          'Group Income Protection',
          'Group Life',
          'Group Life;Group Income Protection',
          'Group PMI',
          'Group Travel Insurance'
        ])
      )
      .andWhereNot('Payable', 0);
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    data.tier2 = results.length;

    return knex(table)
      .select('CRMContactId')
      .where(builder => builder.where('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 3').orWhere('GroupOneCaption', 'Tier 4'))
      .andWhereNot('Payaways Made/Received', 'Payaway Made')
      .andWhere(builder =>
        builder.whereIn('Plantype', [
          'Accident Sickness & Unemployment Insurance',
          'AVC',
          'Discretionary Managed Service',
          'Endowment',
          'Enhanced Pension Annuity',
          'Executive Pension Plan',
          'FSAVC',
          'General Investment Account',
          'Income Drawdown',
          'Income Protection',
          'Individual Retirement Account',
          'Insurance / Investment Bond',
          'Investment Trust',
          'ISA',
          'Long Term Care',
          'Maximum Investment Plan',
          'Money Purchase Contracted',
          'OEIC / Unit Trust',
          'Offshore Bond',
          'Pension Annuity',
          'Pension Term Assurance',
          'Personal Equity Plan',
          'Personal Pension Plan',
          'Regular Savings Plan',
          'Relevant Life Policy',
          's226 RAC',
          's32 Buyout Bond',
          'Savings Account',
          'SIPP',
          'SSAS',
          'Stakeholder Individual',
          'Term Protection',
          'Venture Capital Trust',
          'Whole Of Life',
          'Wrap'
        ])
      )
      .andWhereNot('Payable', 0);
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    data.tier3 = results.length;

    return knex(table)
      .select('CRMContactId')
      .where('FCIRecognition', '>', 500.0)
      .andWhere('IncomeType', 'Renewal Commission');
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    data.largerenewal = results.length;

    return knex.raw(
      `SELECT ContactName AS Adviser, FORMAT(SUM(Payable),2) AS 'Renewal Income' FROM fci_test WHERE IncomeType IN ("Renewal Commission","Fund Based Commission","Ongoing Fee") AND \`Payaways Made/Received\` != 'Payaway Made' GROUP BY ContactName`
    );
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    data.renewalincome = results[0];
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // TODO: send error response
  });
```

However with your coding style you would highly benefit if you use async / await to prevent need for having that global `data` object where results are collected.